# ¿Cómo utilizar un progressbar o un label?

Tags: c#

¿Cómo utilizar un progressbar o en todo caso un label el cual me muestre un mensajes que el archivo ha sido copiado correctamente?

```
private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        string nombreArchivo = Path.GetFileName(btn2.Text);
        string destino = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"\documento\", nombreArchivo);
        System.IO.File.Copy(btn2.Text, destino, true);


    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: label.content = "archivo copiado"; Que es lo que estas preguntando.. y un label es muy diferente a un progress bar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas SoyKrut,

Puedes usar un [ProgressBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar(v=vs.110).aspx) de la siguiente forma:

```
private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Ponemos el valor mínimo del ProgressBar
   progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
   // Ponemos el valor máximo del ProgressBar (en tu caso 1 archivo)
   progressBar1.Maximum = 1;
   // Ponemos el valor inicial.
   progressBar1.Value = 0;
   // Declaramos el numero que va a sumar cada vez que ejecutemos el PerformStep
   progressBar1.Step = 1;

   string nombreArchivo = Path.GetFileName(btn2.Text);
   string destino = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"\documento\", nombreArchivo);
   System.IO.File.Copy(btn2.Text, destino, true);

   //Aquí avanzas un paso del ProgressBar.
   progressBar1.PerformStep();

   //Ponemos en el label un mensaje indicando que se ha copiado el archivo correctamente.
   label1.Text = "Archivo copiado correctamente!";
}
```

Comment: Hola Marc. El autor no ha mostrado su intento de Progressbar,. Has de esperar a que edite la pregunta para que sobre su codigo explicarle que tiene mal y como mejorarlo. Un saludo

Comment: Marc, aunque tu respuesta es correcto, no seria mejor esperar a que Op clarifique que quiere? el progress bar no hace nada en este caso (es mas, hasta se podria reemplazar con una imagen).